# Access to the tags from a NavigableString

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I really don't understand how BeautifulSoup works. I'm trying this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def strip_del(soup):
    for d in soup.find_all('del'):
        d.decompose()

def num_there(s):
    return any(i.isdigit() for i in s)

def is_airfield(tr):
    return not num_there(tr.td.span.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
strip_del(soup)

for tr in soup.table.tbody:
    if is_airfield(tr):
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

But when I run, I have an error which say me that I can't access to *td* from a `NaviagableString` in my `is_airfield` function.

So my question is why this doesn't work and how work BeautifulSoup ?!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning at `NavigableString` instead of a `tag`.  I would change to using the `find_all` method and see how it works.

```
for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    if is_airfield(tr):
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but what if I want the tr from soup.table.tbody? When I do the find_all() on it I have an error...

Comment: I believe you can chain the `find`s together.  Such as `soup.find("table").find("tbody").find_all("tr")`  Note that this will only get the first table.  If you are interested in a table that isn't first you will have to distinguish it by the `class` or `title` or some other property.

Answer (score 0):

The reason what you are doing does not work is because inside your soup are two kinds of objects, tags and NavigableString's (there may be more but I do not know of what those would be). As you may have been able to glean from the documentation all of BeautifulSoup's methods of navigating the soup are available to tags. They are not available to NavigableStrings, which are often mixed in the soup too.

When you are searching through your soup you should ensure that you only call methods that are available to tags on tags, and methods that are only applicable to NavigableStrings on those. This can be accomplished by using an if condition or a try except block. You can test if an object in the soup is a NavigableString by `import NavigableString` and then using the `isinstance(obj, NavigableString)` method in the if statement to distinguish between NavigableStrings and regular tags.